# Making covariant interface backward compatible

Tags: c#, .net, generics, interface, covariance

We have an interface to deal with DAL with pretty simple definition:

```
interface IRepository<T> : IQueriable<T> // so we can read data from database
{
   Save(T document); // dozen of methods here
}
```

Mostly we use two implementations: real version and in memory version for unit testing. Here is declarations of one of class:

```
public RealRepository : IRepository<AccountEntity> { ... } 
// typical IOC usage
services.AddSingleton<IRepository<AccountEntity>, RealRepository<AccountEntity>>();
```

Now we are working to spin off for main codebase to custom version of project and we need custom fields in data and occassional custom behavior in repository. Most of classes are fine with base implementation but others would require specific implementation. So my goal is to get to following services in:

```
var repository = new RealRepository<CustomAccountEntity>();
services.AddSingleton(IRepository<AccountEntity>, repository);
// for new classes
services.AddSingleton(IRepository<CustomAccountEntity>, repository);
```

I tried to add `out T` to IRepository but I am using T in input parameters and this gave compile time "Invalid variance" error.

I can see a solution by adding second type parameter to interface so it looks like:

```
IRepository<TBase, out TChild> : IQueriable<TChild> {
    Save (T document);
}
```

**Finally, Question: How can make change 100% backward compatible?**

What I tried:

1. Add `IRepository<T>: IRepository<T,T>` -> complies, but `RealRepository` is not implementing `IRepository` anymore.
2. Add 2 interfaces in implementation: `public class RealRepository<TBase, TChild>: IRepository<TBase, TChild>, IRepository<TChild>` but this gives compliation error 'cannot implement both ... and ... because they may unify for some type parameter substitutions'

Answer (score 1):

`Save(T document)` has `T` in a *contravariant* position. That means `in T`, **not** `out T`.

Let's recap what contravariance means. Suppose you had this code:

```
using System;

public class Entity {}
public class AccountEntity : Entity {}
public class CustomAccountEntity : AccountEntity {}

public interface IQueryable<in T>
    where T : Entity
{}

public interface IRepository<in T>
    where T : Entity
{
    void Save(T record);
}

public class EntityRepository<T> : IRepository<T>
    where T : Entity
{
    public void Save(T record) {}
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // This is ***VALID***:
        IRepository<CustomAccountEntity> repo = new EntityRepository<AccountEntity>();
        Console.WriteLine(repo == null ? "cast is invalid" : "cast is valid");
    }
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/cnEdcm

So whenever you need a `IRepository<CustomAccountEntity>`, you can use a concrete  `EntityRepository<AccountEntity>` instance. Seems counter-intuitive, but it's actually totally right: If the concrete method is `Save(AccountEntity)`, it can obviously handle `CustomAccountEntity` instances too; OTOH if the concrete method were `Save(CustomAccountEntity)`, it would NOT be able to handle simple `AccountEntity` instances.

Having said that, then I think you should

1. Use contravariance instead;
2. Declare all dependencies using the most specialised type, e.g. `IRepository<CustomWhateverEntity>`;
3. In the IoC registration code, for each particular entity, setup either `Repository<CustomeWhateverEntity>`, if you need the extra behaviour, or just `Repository<WhateverEntity>` otherwise.

Comment: IQueriable inherited from IEnumerable, and IEnumerable defined as Covariant:
public interface IEnumerable<out T> : System.Collections.IEnumerable

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. Are you talking about `System.Linq.IQueryable`? So it's with an Y, not an I. Because of the difference in spelling, I assumed your `IQueriable` was a custom, user-made interface (and then I actually used `IQueryable` in my example, which is valid, but I guess did not help). Anyway, bottom line is: if you're actually implementing `System.Linq.IQueryable`, and you *want* to do it, then you're out of luck: `IRepository<T>` cannot be both covariant and contravariant.